# Do alkanes evaporate faster than alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, hydrogen-bond

If so, is it because alchohols have hydrogen bonds?

Which type of compound evaporates faster, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, alkanes do evaporate faster than their corresponding alcohols (i.e. an alkane boils at a lower temperature than an alcohol with the same number of carbon atoms). This effect is due to hydrogen bonding between the alcohol hydroxyl groups.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol#Physical_and_chemical_properties) says:

> Because of hydrogen bonding, alcohols tend to have higher boiling points than comparable hydrocarbons and ethers. The boiling point of the alcohol ethanol is 78.29 °C, compared to 69 °C for the hydrocarbon hexane (a common constituent of gasoline), and 34.6 °C for diethyl ether.